# Minimum intensity fringes are not perfectly dark in diffraction pattern?

Tags: optics, waves, interference, double-slit-experiment, diffraction

I am studying Interference and Diffraction and everywhere I look it is written that "In an interference pattern,the minima are usually perfectly dark while in a diffraction pattern they are not so." However no explanation is provided.

Looking at the intensity graph or even the intensity function it can be seen that at minima intensity is 0. Then why is it said that it is not perfectly dark?

Comment: look at the definitions  for diffraction : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/diffracon.html  and for interference http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/interfcon.html . There is incoherence of the waves involved in diffraction,